# Convert a scala list with key value pairs into a spark data frame using only the values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala and spark and I am trying to turn a list that is in the format of [key: string, value: string] into a spark data frame.

The list looks something like this:
(key, [{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}])`

I would like to turn it into a data frame which looks something like

```
+------+------+
|field1|field2|
+------+------+
|value1|value2|
+------+------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this ``` [{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}]``` string ??

Comment: yeah its a string

Comment: Check below solution, let me know if its not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

`value` as `String`

```
scala> val df = Seq(("key","""[{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}]""")).toDF("key","value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: string]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType = ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true)

scala> df.select($"key",explode(from_json($"value",schema)).as("value")).select($"value"("field1").as("field1"),$"value"("field2").as("field2")).show(false)
+------+------+
|field1|field2|
+------+------+
|value1|value2|
+------+------+
```

`value` as `Map`

```
scala> val df = Seq(("key",Seq(Map("field1" -> "value1","field2" -> "value2")))).toDF("key","value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: array<map<string,string>>]

scala> df.select($"key",explode($"value").as("value")).select($"value"("field1").as("field1"),$"value"("field2").as("field2")).show(false)
+------+------+
|field1|field2|
+------+------+
|value1|value2|
+------+------+
```